# Opening status bar notification from code in android

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to open status bar notification from code? I already tried checking NotificationManager but found only methods that close current notifications. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering it's possible to open if you provide package name:

> ```
>  Intent i = new Intent();
>     i.setPackage(sbn.getPackageName());
>     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>     startActivity(i);
> ```